How to handle helper functions used in Zig tests?
Seems functions can't be declared inside Zig's test blocks. Are there any guidelines for how to deal with functions used exclusively in test blocks, i.e., for cleanup?
test "messy test that requires cleanup" {
  createManyFiles();
  defer deleteTestFiles(); // Used only for testing

  expect(something);
}


The standard library makes them private and puts them above the test (example)
fn createManyFiles() {
   ... only used in a test
}
fn deleteTestFiles() {
   ... only used in a test
}
test "messy test that requires cleanup" {
  createManyFiles();
  defer deleteTestFiles();

  try std.testing.expect(something);
}

Zig only compiles functions that are used, so your regular build will not have any test functions in it.
If test functions are needed in multiple files, they can be made public or moved into their own file. They still won't be included in a regular build unless they are used outside of a test.

Seems functions can't be declared inside Zig's test blocks

You technically can do this, by embedding a function in a struct.
test "function in test" {
    const MyStruct = struct{
        fn myFunction() void {}
    };
    MyStruct.myFunction();
}

It's best to avoid this when you can.
